# Url rewriting with intelligencia rule not working

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting, web-config

Im using Intelligencia UrlRewriter for url rewriting. I have wrote a set of rules in the web.config file

I have two sets pages,

1. Static pages whose name is static but content is CMS based
2. Dynamic pages (actually this is not simply a dynamic page its a category which have description and sub categories)

Here both pages are being rewritten from the config file.

1. For instance home page, about us page etc tis is being rewritten as

   rewrite url="~/Home" to="~/Default.aspx"
2. The category page is being the same kind of url its being rewritten as

   rewrite url="~/(.*)" to="~/GroupHome.aspx?Group=$1"

I have given the rules for the static pages first and then the category url but all the urls are being rewritten to grouphome, even if I have given the rule for home page, about us page etc before the category rule.

I have tried even the ollowing still its directing to Group home,

```
<rewrite url="~/Home" to="~/Default.aspx"/>
<rewrite url="~/(.*)/" to="~/GroupHome.aspx?Group=$1"/>
<rewrite url="~/Home" to="~/Default.aspx"/>
```

How the rule can be rewritten to include both urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the processing attribute to false - the documentation says the default behaviour for this is continue, which would then run the next rule:

> Processing - Optional: What to do
>   after processing the action: continue
>   to the next action, stop or restart
>   from the beginning. The default is
>   continue.

Taken from the [rewrite documentation page](http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/actions/rewrite).